# Are there algorithms with proven upper bounds but no proven lower bound (above constant time)?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory

One of my professors mentioned such algorithms exist but could not think of any offhand. Obviously any algorithm will be at least $\mathcal{O(1)}$, but are there algorithms not yet proven to have a lower bound greater than this, which do have a proven upper bound?

I'm interested in both problems and algorithms, but in either case practical examples (if they exist) as opposed to artificial ones.

Comment: It’s easy to construct artificial examples, say an algorithm that looks for a proof of statement X of length at most $n$. If X is provable, then this runs in (essentially) constant time, otherwise in exponential time.

Comment: Are you interested in *algorithms* or *problems*?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Both, I suppose, but in either case practical examples (if they insist) as opposed to artificial ones

Comment: Can you include all this information in your post?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus done. Also my earlier comment was supposed to be *exist not insist

Comment: Most (non-randomized) algorithms need to read the full input (in TM speak), which imposes a $\Omega(n)$ lower bound. That's not a universal law -- a TM can decide in constant time whether a binary number is even if it's given in LSB encoding -- but it holds for most interesting algorithms. In the RAM model, of course, it works a little differently, but the principle applies.

Comment: Note that saying "at least O(_)" is a nonsensical statement, just like "at least something smaller than x". Use $\Omega$, $\omega$, and $\Theta$ to properly express lower buonds.

Comment: A practical algorithm whose lower bound is less than $\Omega(n)$ is binary search, whose lower bound in the RAM model is $\Omega(\log n)$. Others are the various operations on various binary heaps. I suspect that your professor meant there were algorithms not yet proven to have a lower bound greater than $\Omega(n)$, which do have a proven upper bound.

Answer (score 2):

To try and answer your question:

Yes. generally lower bound is much harder to prove than upper bound.
That is, to prove an upper bound, you must only show one algorithm that solves problem $A$ in $t_1(n)$ time.

To prove a lower bound $t_2(n)$ for the same problem $A$, you must show that ANY algorithm that solves $A$ MUST work in at least $t_2(n)$ time.

Take the median for example (under the comparison model). There is a recursive algorithm that solves the median problem in $O(n)$ time. That means any greater upper bound is moot, and any greater lower bound is wrong.

However a precise lower bound for the median is an open question. The algorithm mentioned above performs $c*n$ comparisons, where $c$ ~ $17$. It has been proven that for selection of median, a total of $\Omega(\frac{3n}{2})$ comparisons is required (which means a better algorithm does not exist).

However, we don't know if a greater lower bound exist. Proving a $\frac{5n}{2}$ comparisons lower bound is an open question!

Comment: $\Omega$ ignores constant factors.

Comment: $2n$ comparison and a bit more is required to find the median  as shown by _Median Selection Requires (2+epsilon)n Comparisons_ 
by Dorit Dor , Uri Zwick. So, this answer does not fully answer the question.